# Crear script en linux con ficheros

Tags: linux, script

Parto de tres ficheros
conficovid que tiene la ruta de los dos archivos que voy a usar

ciudades que contiene:
madrid
BARCELONA
SEVILLA

habitantes que contiene:
DNI / CIUDAD / 1VAC/2VAC/3VAC
11111A/MADRID/SI/SI/NO

A partir de una ciudad del archivo ciudades.txt
Calcular el porcentaje de vacunados de esa ciudad del archivo habitantes
Para ello tengo que usar el while read

No acabo de entender como pasar del archivo ciudades al habitantes para que me lea la ciudad
Como introducir esa ciudad para que se inicie el codigo. Muchas gracias

```
#!/bin/bash



if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then 


echo "Tienes que introducir dos Parametros"

echo "Parametro 1: Script"

echo "Parametro 2: Fichero"

exit 1

fi


condficovid=$1



if [ ! -f $1 ]; then 


echo "El fichero  $1 con los datos no existe"

exit 1

fi 

ficheroHab=$(cat conficovid.txt |grep habitantes |cut -d "=" -f2)

ficheroCiud=$(cat conficovid.txt |grep ciudades |cut -d "=" -f2)


if [ ! -f $ficheroHab ]; then 

echo "El fichero $ficheroHab con los datos no existe"

exit 1

fi

if [ ! -f $ficheroCiu ]; then 

echo "El fichero $ficheroCiu con los datos no existe"

exit 1

fi


ciudadusu=$1

ciudad=$(echo $linea)


while read linea; do 

contador1=0

contador2=0

contador3=0

contadorTotal=0

totalVacunados1=0

totalVacunados2=0

totalVacunados3=0


ciudadHab=$(echo $linea |cut -d ";" -f2)

vacuna1=$(echo $linea |cut -d ";" -f3)

vacuna2=$(echo $linea |cut -d ";" -f4)

vacuna3=$(echo $linea |cut -d ";" -f5)


if [ $ciudad == $ciudadHab ]; then 

contadorTotal=$(($contadorTotal+1))


        if [ $vacuna1 == "SI" ]; then 

        contador1=$(($contador1+1))

        fi

        if [ $vacuna2 == "SI" ]; then 

        contador2=$(($contador2+1))

        fi

        if [ $vacuna3 == "SI" ]; then 

        contador3=$(($contador3+1))

        fi

else

echo "No hay datos de vacunacion de $2"

exit 1

fi

done<habitantes.txt

done<ciudades.txt


totalVacunados1=$((($contador1*100)/$contadorTotal))

totalVacunados2=$((($contador2*100)/$contadorTotal))

totalVacunados3=$((($contador3*100)/$contadorTotal))


echo $ciudad

echo "1 Dosis: $contador1 %"

echo "2 Dosis: $contador2 %"

echo "3 Dosis: $contador3 %"
```